# How are quotient maps by distance-zero relation used in mathmatics?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, metric-spaces

Let us consider $\mathbb{R}^2_{\neq 0}$ space equipped with distance metric $d(x_1, x_2) = \mathbb{angle}(x_1, x_2)$. In such case, considering a equivalence relation between $x \sim y$ is $d(x, y) = 0$, we can consider a quotient space $\mathbb{R}^2_{\neq0}/\sim$ and it is homemorhpic to a circle.

This distance metric by angle is just an example, and I'm interested in the quotient map with distance-zero relation.

Is there common in mathematics field to consider such a quotient map by distance-zero relation? And if so, in what particular field and for what in particular, such a map is used?

I searched over mathstackexchange, and found only [Working with Equivalence Classes and Metric Space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2481060/working-with-equivalence-classes-and-metric-space) But for me the quotient map by distance-zero relation is interesting and should be heavily used in some mathematical area.

Comment: Perhaps a more interesting example would be one where (defining $x\sim y$ to mean $d(x,y)=$) $x_1\sim x_2$, $y_1\sim y_2$ does not mean $d(x_1,y_1)=d(x_2,y_2)$. EDIT: Never mind - the triangle inequality implies that this is impossible! So the metric always factors through the quotient space.

Comment: In a standard metric space, distances of $0$ between different points aren't allowed. f we generalise the definition of metric spaces so that is allowed, then the quotient you are talking about is the same as the Kolmogorov quotient for topological spaces.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudometric_space

Comment: The most standard example is the Cauchy-completion: You define a pseudo-metric space consisting of Cauchy sequence. The Cauchy-completion is the quotient by the zero-distance relation.